# I can't figure out why my js script isn't actually navigating to another page by using querySelector()

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a queryselector in my script which is set to match a **singular** element on a page which is a "Next" button. Normally when the user clicks this button it would take them to the next question. I have confirmed that the selector is working by using firefox dev edition's instant evaluation and have used basic console.log statements to make sure my script was making it to where the queryselector would be evaluating to the button. For whatever reason though, even if I delete EVERY other button on the page, the .click() function for that button **still** navigates the browser to a page other than the one that the next button brings the user to **every** time I have run it as a single line outside of my program.

this is the element I am matching to:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn submit_button quiz_submit btn-secondary" id="submit_quiz_button" data-action="">
      Submit Quiz
    </button>`
```

this is the selector I'm using

```
document.querySelector("div#questions.assessing div.button-container input#last_question_id+button.Button.submit_button.next-question")
```

Comment: A. Where is the navigation code? B. Why not use ```document.querySelector("#submit_quiz_button")``` simpler, more readable?

Comment: I added to the selector because I thought that it was too vague and matching the other button. I now know that is not the problem but I have yet to change it back. I didn't post the navigation code for privacy reasons as it contains my user id and the url.

Comment: You need not show your user id and any private data in any case. For testing purposes, use something like ```https://cnn.com``` or similar. And for any parameter set fake value

Comment: I tried setting the data for the relative link to be another page and it still did the same thing.